# How to consume Webservice in Mule using wsdl-cxf component

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Hi I was exploring **wsdl-cxf** for consuming a web service ... I have the following Mule flow :-

```
<stdio:connector name="stdioConnector" promptMessage="Enter Value :" doc:name="STDIO"/>

<flow name="ServiceFlow" doc:name="ServiceFlow">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="mainData" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<cxf:jaxws-service  serviceClass="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.MainData"  doc:name="SOAP"/>
<component class="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl" doc:name="JavaMain_ServiceImpl"/>
</flow>

<flow name="inputService" doc:name="inputService" >
<stdio:inbound-endpoint system="IN" doc:name="STDIO"/>
<logger message="Payyyload : #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<outbound-endpoint address="wsdl-cxf:http://localhost:8082/mainData?WSDL&amp;method=retrieveDataOperation" doc:name="Generic"/>
<stdio:outbound-endpoint system="OUT" doc:name="STDIO"/>
<mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
</flow>
```

Now the first flow  **ServiceFlow**  is the web service exposed which is working perfectly when the following input is given from SOAPUI :-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:retrieveDataRequest>
         <v1:Id>33</v1:Id>
      </v1:retrieveDataRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It fetch the data from DB and display the result ...
The second flow **inputService** try to consume the service using **wsdl-cxf** ... Here I used **stdio:inbound** for taking the input .. Now when I pass the Data 33 as input .. it does not able to fetch the value from DB ... Now my web service implement class has the following method :-

```
public DataResponse retrieveDataOperation(
            RetrieveRequest retrieveDataRequest)
{
//All the Logic here 
}
```

where RetrieveRequest retrieveDataRequest is the Object type as input  .. So how can I pass the value using **wsdl-cxf** here which may be taking a String request ... what I mean is how to use **wsdl-cxf** to consume a webservice and pass a value which is taking Object as parameter ... Please help ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/WSDL+Connectors):

> The one limitation of the CXF WSDL provider is that it does not allow you to use non-Java primitives (objects that are not a String, int, double, and so on).

Your web service receives a `retrieveDataRequest` object, not a simple type, so the provider can't be used in your use case.